# VBScript is taking long time/not executing when I am executing via Java, but it runs when I am executing it via command prompt?

Tags: java, excel, vbscript

`test.vbs` file contains following snippet..

```vb
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\testing\new1.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set Sheeet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'The above script is working when I execute manually via command prompt

Sheeet1.Activate
Sheeet1.TextBox1.value = "C:\testing\"
objWorkbook.Save

objExcel.Application.Run "Execute Calculator"

objWorkbook.Save
objWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Quit

Set Sheeet1 = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Above snippet works fine when I doubleclick on `test.vbs` file. But it fails to run/waiting for infinite time without any error or warning with Java Executor thread.

Software Configuration:

- Excel 2013
- Windows 7 OS

Above script is working in Windows 10 and Excel 2016 version.

What is the problem, is there any security setting changes required in PC? Can anybody give the solution, who come across this issue?

Comment: seems like you trying to work with Excel in GUI in script (`objExcel.Application.Visible = True`). And seems like you cannot do it from thread in Executor service.

Comment: You should also show the relevant java code.

Comment: @gooamoko Thanks for your reply, if that is the case, it should not work in all cases